# Window's Vista Paint's HTML color codes

Tags: html, colors, windows-vista

I need to know the html color code for the default brown in Vista's Paint application.

Does anybody know this? Or does anybody know how I can find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean the brown in the colour palette at the top? If it is the same as in Win8 then it is #B97A57. (The value of the color-name `brown` used in css is #A52A2A.)

You can probably find this value from within Paint but I used the colour-picker tool in [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/en/).

Comment: If someone has Vista and it is a different value then I will delete my answer.

Comment: Thank you Andy! That color is a bit off from what I have, and I don't know how to figure it out from Paint. It'd be great if you could tell me how to find out from Paint, but otherwise I'll just deal with what I have. Thanks again.

Comment: It would obviously be better if someone with Vista advised you but.. click on the brown colour and click the Edit Color button (which is to the right in Windows 8), this should give you the RGB colour numbers. You can use some online tool to convert these into their #number.